# Складні випадки постановки тире у безсполучниковому складному реченні

Tags: пунктуація, синтаксис

Любі друзі, допоможіть, будь ласка, з’ясувати причини постановки тире у складному безсполучниковому реченні:  **Дивлюсь у воду — місяць у воді сміється. (О. Довженко.)**
Прочитала у [статті](http://shkolyar.in.ua/syntaksys-skldnogo-rechennya/bezpoluchnykove) про написання розділових знаків у БСР, що знаки ставляться відповідно до інтонації.

Тире ставиться між частинами безсполучникового речення, якщо:

1. Зміст частини складного речення **протиставляється або зіставляється, порівнюється (можна підставити а, але, мов...)**: Мало прожити життя — треба життя зрозуміть.
2. Друга частина речення виражає **наслідок, несподіваний результат, висновок** з того, про що говорилося в першій частині речення: На годину спізнишся — за рік не доженеш.
3. У першій частині вказується на **умову**, за якої відбувається дія в другій частині: Защебече соловейко в лузі на калині — заспіває козаченько, ходя по долині.
4. Відбувається **швидка зміна подій**: Виглянуло сонце — озеро вмить проясніло, радісно посміхнулось до неба.

Жоден із перелічених варіантів, я вважаю, не відповідає інтонації мого речення. Але у правилі про двокрапку є відповідний пункт:

Двокрапка ставиться, якщо друга частина складного речення **розкриває, пояснює або доповнює зміст першої частини (між частинами речення можна поставити слова а саме, що; і побачив; і почув, що)**. Знаю: з попелу сходять квіти.

Як пояснити таку невідповідність інтонації написанню? Може, я ще не враховую іншого варіанту?

Comment: А що, під п.3 хіба не підпадає?

Comment: Подивіться в контексті - https://goo.gl/t2w1j4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насправді, ви практично відповіли на запитання.
Це речення цілком підпадає під п.2, а саме, **причинно-наслідковий звʼязок між частинами складного речення**. Просто на перший погляд не зовсім очевидно, яким чином друга частина є **наслідком** із першої. Здавалося б, *місяць сміється* не може бути наслідком того, що *дивлюся у воду*.

Але все стає на свої місця, якщо вставити логічну ланку:

> *Дивлюсь у воду — **і бачу, що** місяць у воді сміється.*

---

Стосовно ж правила використання двокрапки, на практиці можна вважати двокрапку як *обернений* знак до тире. Тобто, якщо маємо `A ⇒ B` (Причина — Наслідок), то `B ⇐ A` (Наслідок: Причина).

Від себе зауважу, що смислові відтінки іноді бува важко розрізнити. Особисто для мене, хорошою практикою несподівано стало читання японської поезії в українському перекладі. Наприклад [**Мацуо Басьо** у перекладі Миколи Лукаша](http://maysterni.com/publication.php?id=10475)

> *Пущу коня вбрід —
>
>   полегесеньку впишусь
>
>   в літній краєвид.*

Тут просто причина і наслідок.

---

> *Цілував би — жаль:
>
>   од моїх пекучих сліз
>
>   іней піде в тань...*

Тут складніше: тире є замінником до пропущеного слова, якщо я вірно розумію (моʼ, варто почитати оригінал), а двокрапка поєднує наслідок *жаль* і причину (2-3 рядки).

---

> *Мандрівник — і все:
>
>   це тепер моє ім'я.
>
>   Йде осінній дощ.*

Тут, *мандрівник* — причина, *і все* — наслідок, другий рядок — уточнення наслідку.